# SQL Group By, case when on aggregated

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can't wrap my mind around the next task:
I have a table, with some `key`, which represents some kind of group id. I would like to `GROUP BY` by this key and in resulted table show some columns from this table depending on the column value:
If all the values in this group by this `key` in `col1` are equal (same number or text), then show this exact value, if they are different (at least one of them) - show some kind like "Others".

**Example**

```
key col1
1     1
1     1
1     1
2     4
2     5
```

**Resulted table:**

```
key col1
1     1
2     Others
```

Postgres 9.4, if this matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `case`:

```
select key,
       (case when min(col1) = max(col1) then min(col1)
             else 'others'
        end) as col1
from t
group by key;
```

Comment: @SimonOsipov . . . Yes.